# Inserting float value to mysql database inconsistency

Tags: .net, mysql, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework and mysql as a backend.

I have an entity that has lat and long which are of type float.

Let's say the values are lat:45.50818 and long:-73.55409

after the insert in the db the values in the DB are lat:45.508183 and
long:-73.554092

in the db the type is float (10,6)

where does the extra 3 and 2 coming from?

Also when I query the db my entity contains the correct lat/long ...

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use decimal data type instead

```
decimal(10,6)
```

[Flaoting point numbers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) are only approximate numbers. Defining `float(10,6)`means only that you can store that precision but the number may be inaccurate after that precision. Fixed-point numbers don't have that problem.

Comment: will try, but do you know the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Note that `decimal` is a floating point type too. It's not really that floating point numbers are "only approximate numbers" - it's that they can't represent *every possible number* exactly, and in particular *binary* floating point numbers can't represent some "simple" numbers exactly, such as 0.1.

Comment: Put Simply, Decimal values are precise.  Float is not.  Float allows for imprecision and faster calculations when precision isn't important. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c